# How to debug extremely fuzzy / distorted guitar sound from Bias FX 2 via Focusrite 2i2?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I am recording guitar sound in Reaper via a Focusrite Scarlet 2i2 (2nd Gen) interface, using the Bias FX 2 plugin. I've tried nearly all of the presets in the plugin and they all give a very fuzzy and overly distorted sound -- I'm not sure how to describe it but it doesn't sound right. The gain on the focusrite is turned all the way down. I get the same problem using the standalone Bias FX 2 program. My guitar is an Ibanez S621QM with hum-bucker pickups.

[Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3r1jtkw01v92kd/guitar_sample.wav?dl=0) to a sample, I'm just playing some open and power chords. This sample is using the "Rock > Back To 80's" preset.

If someone could offer advice on how to debug this I'd appreciate it!

Comment: How does it sound with the effect/amp sim completely bypassed?

Comment: Here is a link to the clean sound: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lazigxdtj7dm6gw/guitar_sample_clean.wav?dl=0

Comment: If you check out this video https://youtu.be/qsTBdm5dM-8?t=195, his tone sounds a lot more vibrant and clean / professional. Maybe my playing is just not great?

Answer (score 2):

We can be almost certain, based on the pristine clean sample you've given, that the problem is not anything wrong with the guitar, interface, or drivers.  It's likely you just aren't able to dial in the tones you like in the software.  You may learn something from copying the settings in that (or some other) video.  There are some big differences between your tone and the tone you're comparing to, such as your fast and loud delay/reverb and lower gain.

Also notice that he stays away from open chords for the demo.  Open chords and lots of distortion don't usually play nicely.  He sticks to power chords and single notes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see by the meters on the Scarlett whether or not it is clipping. Make sure the input is set to INST and not MIC. If you have hot pickups you may need to engage the pad even with the gain turned all the way down.

As a test, simply roll back the volume on the guitar. When you do that, does it improve?

If the Scarlett isn't clipping, then you might investigate your buffer size settings in the Focusrite control panel. That's about all I can think of.